# My inventory and armor disappeared in LAN multiplayer on Minecraft

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

My friend and I were playing Minecraft over LAN, and my friend was the host, then she logged off. 5 minutes later we tried to log back in and all my stuff was gone, and I wasn't even in the same spot where I was previously.
I don't know what happened. She was playing over Windows and I was using iOS.

I need my stuff back, I was so happy because I had found diamonds for the first time in my life :(

Comment: There is a lot that is unclear here. But let me start by asking whether your inventory was completely empty or reverted to a previous state.

Comment: I assume your friend was playing the Minecraft Windows 10 version, right?

Comment: yes, my inventory was full and i was fully armored.

Comment: yes, my friend was playing on minecraft windows 10 version.

Comment: It probably just didn't save properly when she exited.

Answer (score 1):

If she was hosting the LAN and she logged off before you could (Save and quit) then it is likely that a saving error occurred on your device, because you couldn't save before the host logged off.  To prevent this you should log-off before the host of the LAN closes.

Comment: You could test to see if the diamonds you found are where you found them before, if they are then it was a saving problem. (If you know where they are)

Answer (score 0):

If you were not logged in and you changed your name this makes the game think you are a different person playing on the same console/device. Therefore if you were to change your name back to the original your problem would be solved.